# Django email translation only works locally

Tags: python, django, email, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send translated emails to my users according to their language set in user.language. In order to do this I override the send_mail method from my BaseMailerService.

```
from django.utils.translation import override

    class BaseTranslatedMailerService(BaseMailerService):
        """
        Renders the acutal content of an email according to the users configurated
        language.
        """

        def send_mail(self, context, attachments=None):
            recipient_obj = context.get('recipient').get('user_obj')
            # Default for all language settings is 'en'
            with override(recipient_obj.language):
                return super(BaseTranslatedMailerService, self).send_mail(context=context,
                                                                          attachments=attachments)
```

Locally, in my tests I get it to send the translated versions of the mail according to user.language but in my server environment it just sends the English mails every time. Maybe it has to do something with thread language I have to set?

Answer (score 0):

Appearantly I accidentally added all *.mo files to my gitignore causing my compiled language strings to be excluded from the deploy process. Removing *.mo from gitignore therefor solved my problem.